# Display product attributes for current product

Tags: php, loop, taxonomy, tags, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to display the attributes of the current product. In the screenshot below, I declared the attribute "Liquor Brands" and assigned multiple values to it:

[image]

Here is the code I'm currently working on:

```
        <?php

        $liquor = new WP_Query( array( 
            'post_type'   => 'product',
            'product_cat' => 'liquors',
            'meta_query'  => array(
                array(
                    'key'   => '_stock_status',
                    'value' => 'instock'
                )
            )
        ) );

        if ( $liquor->have_posts() ) : while ( $liquor->have_posts() ) : $liquor->the_post();

        ?>

        <?php 

        $liquor_brands = get_terms('pa_liquor-brands');
        foreach ( $liquor_brands as $liquor_brand ) :
        ?>

        <?php endforeach; ?>



        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"  class="three columns product-post">

        <?php echo $liquor_brand->slug ?>

        </div>



        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; else: ?>

        <?php //error message ?>

        <?php endif; ?>


        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Here is the screenshot of the output. It only shows the last value that I have set, which is "very-old-captain-rum":

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're initializing the `$liquor_brands` array, running it through a `foreach` loop that does nothing, then echoing out the slug of `$liquor_brand` outside of the `foreach` loop. `$liquor_brand` is going to be set to the last item in the `$liquor_brands` array since the whole array was iterated over. Long story short, you should do the echoing inside of the `foreach` loop:

```
<?php

    $liquor = new WP_Query( array( 
        'post_type'   => 'product',
        'product_cat' => 'liquors',
        'meta_query'  => array(
            array(
                'key'   => '_stock_status',
                'value' => 'instock'
            )
        )
    ) );

    if ( $liquor->have_posts() ) : while ( $liquor->have_posts() ) : $liquor->the_post(); ?>

        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"  class="three columns product-post">
            <?php 
                $liquor_brands = get_terms( 'pa_liquor-brands' );
                foreach ( $liquor_brands as $liquor_brand ) {
                    echo $liquor_brand->slug . ' ';
                }
            ?>
        </div>

        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; else: ?>

        <?php //error message ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: I think you actually want to use `$liquor_brand->name`. The slug is not supposed to have spaces. Check out the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) (particularly the examples at the bottom) for details on the available properties.

Comment: I see, so there is no way to add spaces between the slugs.

Comment: I misunderstood. Yes, you can just add a space after each one. Updated the code.